# is there a decent way to implant some bijectors inside a bijector in tensorflow_probability?

Tags: tensorflow-probability

Let's say I want to build a bijector, and there's a two tfp.bijectors inside of it. Cuz it's a tfb.Bijector, I have to implement `_forward_log_det_jacobian` method.

```
class Bij(tfb.Bijector):
    def __init___(...):
        super().__init__(..., forward_min_event_ndims=3)
        self.bi1 = Bijector1()
        self.bi2 = Bijector2()

    def _forward(self, x):
        x = self.bi1.forward(x)
        # some ops on x here
        return self.bi2.forward(x)
        # I hope the way it forwards is right, I can't just chain them up cuz some ops on x between bi1 and bi2. If there's better way to achieve this, pls let me know!

    ...
    
    def _forward_log_det_jacobian(self, x):
        # I am a bit confused here. I use bi1.forward_log_det_jacobian(x) to get
        # jaconbian then summed it with bi2.forward_log_det_jacobian(x) with parameter
        # event_ndims = forward_min_event_ndims in both forward_log_det_jacobian().
```

The output seems to be right but I am not quite sure, since `bi1` is a chain which contains a `forward_min_event_ndims`=1(<3) bijector.

Is there a recommended way to achieve something like this? Or is the way I wrote correct?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `tfb.Chain`?
Also bijectors have a `__call__` method implemented which will give you a Chain instance, i.e. `chain = bij1(bij2)`.